# Glassfish warning when i try to open an existing Java Project

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

the project itself is located in my home-directory, netbeans and glassfish each installed to opt. when i start IDE and open java project i get following warning five times:

`/opt/glassfish-3.0.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/wss-server-config-2.0.xml (Permission denied)`

thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

What is the permission of the glassfish and netbeans folder in opt? You can verify that with:

```
ls -l /opt/
```

Depending on the result you might need to change the ownership of the folder to your username. You can do that with the following commands: (replace username with your username, and press tab to autocomplete versions of the software)

```
sudo chown username.users /opt/glassfish-<TAB>
sudo chown username.users /opt/netbeans-<TAB>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried renaming the folder **nbproject** in the project folder, which worked. Simple :-)